# can we preserve correctness of inequality after adjusting all involved exponents?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, exponentiation, real-numbers, exponential-sum

## Problem

Lets assume we have an inequality such that it involves only positive, real values and all exponents within this inequality are integer multiples of $2n$ (even), we suppose this inequality is true.

### Question

If we swap $2n$ with different value, for example $n$, does this preserve validity of this inequality?

### Example

Assume $\alpha_i \geq 0, \forall i$ and we assume there are at least two terms. We know following equation is true

$$ \sum_i \alpha_i^2 \leq ( \sum_i \alpha_i )^2 $$

This equation is verified because we can expand $( \sum_i \alpha_i )^2 = \sum_i \alpha_i^2 + \sum_{j \neq i} \alpha_i \alpha_j$,

Does that imply that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ following statement is also true?

$$ \sum_i \alpha_i^{2n} \leq ( \sum_i \alpha_i^n )^{2n} $$

### Origin of the problem

I have been trying to show the following for positives $\alpha_i$

$$ (\sum_i \alpha_i^4 )^\frac{1}{4} \leq \sum_i \alpha_i^2 $$

Which is difficult to show algebraically, however if stated property is true it reduces to a trivial form mentioned earlier.

Comment: I think you have a typo: for your question, there appears to be an extra $n$ exponent on the right hand side of the inequality being asked about.

Comment: that is intentional, it is supposed to mimic same form as in initial inequality, where $1$ maps to $n$ and $2$ maps to $2n$

Comment: If you have just one term, $\alpha_1 = 1/2$, then consider $n=2$: The LHS of your inequality is $(1/2)^4 = 1/16$ and the RHS of your inequality is $((1/2)^2)^4 = 1/256$. Clearly $1/16 \not \leq 1/256$.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I updated assumptions in the example, we need at least two terms now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false as stated. Here is a concrete counterexample (for the updated version in which there are at least two terms). Given the *two* terms $\alpha_1 =  \alpha_2 = 1/2$, consider when $n=2$.

The LHS of your inequality becomes $(1/2)^4 + (1/2)^4 = 1/8$.

The RHS of your inequality becomes $\big((1/2)^2 + (1/2)^2\big)^4 = (1/2)^4 = 1/16$.

But, $1/8 \not \leq 1/16$.

Comment: Thank you for counter example. Just one remark. Comments cannot be accepted as answers. You always have to write answer, otherwise users using search engine cannot know if question was answered or not. I edited your comment but edit didn't pass peer review. I suggest you edit it yourself.

Comment: @Marek The reason that I included the bracketed remark at the top is, other readers of MSE may mistakenly believe that I simply answered this question as some sort of "low-hanging fruit" - i.e., that there was a typographical error that yields a relatively simple counterexample. In such a scenario, I think a better approach is to clarify by comment whether there was a typo; since you specified it to be "intentional" (although added an additional condition of having two terms) I posted an answer instead of a third comment, and want/ed other MSE users to be able to note this sequence of events.